# own typo3 Extension doesn't get shown in Extension Manager (Composer Mode)

Tags: composer-php, package, typo3, extbase, typo3-extensions

Im trying to set up my own Extension, for having in the all kind of changes to my Site. I set up typo3 9.5.5 via. Composer. The next step was building up my own extension. I followed the official docs and also added a composer.json, but it wont show up in the Extension Manager.

#### ext_emconf

```
<?php
$EM_CONF[$_EXTKEY]=[
'title'=>'MS Site Extension',
'description'=>'TYPO3 Site Extionsion',
'category'=>'plugin',
'author'=>'-',
'author_company'=>'-',
'author_email'=>'-',
'state'=>'alpha',
'clearCacheOnLoad'=>true,
'version'=>'0.0.1',
'constraints'=>[
  'depends'=>[
    'typo3'=>'9.5.5-9.9.99',
  ],
],
'autoload'=>[
  'psr-4'=>[
    'Ms\\MsSite\\'=>'Classes'
  ],
],
];
```

#### composer.json of the extension

```
{
"name": "ms/ms_site",
"type": "typo3-cms-extension",
"description": "MS SITE",
"license": [
"GPL-2.0+"
],
"keywords": [
  "typo3",
  "cms",
  "ms",
  "ms_site"
],
"version": "0.0.1-dev",
"require": {
  "typo3/cms": "^9.5"
},
"autoload-dev": {
  "psr-4": {
    "Ms\\MsSite\\": "Classes/"
  },
  "replace": {
    "hellotypo3": "self.version",
    "typo3-ter/ms_site": "self.version"
  },
  "extra": {
    "typo3/cms": {
      "extension-key": "ms_site"
    }
  }
}
}
```

I'm a bit confused what I have to do now, the only place where my extension currently is, is at: typo3conf/ext, I configured it in the ext_emconf and the composer.json of the extension.

How do I solve this problem?

Edit: Hmm my console tells me that ms_site is added to PackageStates but I still can't see my Extension in my Backend ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm just tilted and dumb, after over 4 hours of searching I recognized my mistake ... I just didnt uploaded the data to my server. :) I thought that I enabled an auto upload but it wasn't.